# How to access Client Printer Active X Control using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am doing a web application in .net with crystal report. I found problem while clicking the print button in the report viewer. The problem is sometimes the activex is not called. Without clicking on the print button of crystal report viewer i want to call it manually from client script. Does jQuery help to get printer active x control?

Regards
Bari

Answer (score 0):

This is not really what jQuery is for.

In my experience, you can't guarantee that a browser will tun ActiveX scripts. Can you imagine the hell that might ensue if some nefarious site downloads some JavaScript to start your printer going.
Hilarious!

Comment: basically this is an in-house web application which will not open to the outside rather it will be used in internal branches.